# Create variables in Excel template that track section columns using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Whenever I want to add new columns to the template a number of values need to be changed in order to keep 'push buttons' aligned.

```
Property Get slp_hide_col() As String
slp_hide_col = "L:T"
End Property
*Seperate from the above code*    
 Private Sub SLP_Config_Click()
With Columns(slp_hide_col)
    .Select
    .EntireColumn.Hidden = Not .EntireColumn.Hidden
End With
  End Sub
```

I wanted to shift the slp_hide_col by a value of each column added. 
Anything would help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create named range for `L:T`. After adding new columns, named range shifts.

Then you can use it as follows:

```
Property Get slp_hide_col() As String
   slp_hide_col = "myNamedRange"
End Property
```

and then change `Columns(slp_hide_col)` to `Range(slp_hide_col)`:

```
Public Sub SLP_Config_Click()
    With Range(slp_hide_col)
        .Select
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = Not .EntireColumn.Hidden
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I keep on getting a  Run-time error '13' Type mismatch though when I make slp_hide_col = "myNamedRange"

Comment: have you added `myNamedRange` into your workbook as in screenshot above?

Comment: Yes I added myNamedRange into my workbook. It still gives me the Run-time error

Comment: See my updated asnwer. You should also change `Columns(slp_hide_col)` to `Range(slp_hide_col)`