# VBA Macro: Formula is Based on a Column that changes locations

Tags: vba, excel

i'm trying to tweak my macro so that it creates a column next to a specific column that always changes positions. In the macro i have below, it is just an absolute reference of 6 columns to the left. However, this wont always be the case. Should I set this up by finding the column name in the top row?

Basically the macro creates a new column and puts in an IF statement if it is a duplicate, and then sets up conditional formatting to highlight all the values of "1". Sorry if i am not explaining this clearly!

```
Sub test()
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-6]=R[-1]C[-6],R[-1]C+1,1)"
    Range("L2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Calculate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you to create named range for your column and than refer to that column using named range rather than address (when you add new columns, named range still referce to your *specific column* and there is no need to adjust your code). See this link for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611698/create-variables-in-excel-template-that-track-section-columns-using-vba/21611768#21611768

Comment: thanks. im looking at the post and it looks useful. but would that only work for me personally? i would like this code to be sent out to a couple others to use, so then they would have to set up the defined range each time?

Comment: are you going to send only code or entire workbook with code? If only code - yes, each person should define named range in their workbook. If you send entire workbook - no, they shoudn't define range again. BTW, if your column has unique header - there is another way, you could use `Find` or `Application.Match` to locate this header

Comment: ah thanks for that clarification. ok i will try to set up the defined range and see if that works. and yes, they are unique headers. we can call the header "ABC". so then FIND could locate that "ABC" column name, but i'm not sure how to tie that into the vba code for an IF statement.

Comment: not sure what `If` statement do you mean, but you could do `set colHeader=Range("1:1").Find(What:="ABC")` and then use `colHeader` variable like this: `colHeader.EntireColumn.Select`

Comment: oh wow awesome the colheader is great! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a working code for this but it requires that your data be in a table. This is the best way to dynamically manipulate and reference the data (Columns, Rows, etc..)

Also I heavily rely on the ListObject method. It really handles tables well.

```
Public Sub InsertColumn(Optional columnName As String, Optional BeforeORAfter As String)
Dim loTableName As ListObject
Dim loColumn As ListColumn
Dim newColDest As Long

'Handles user input if they desire the column inserted before or after
Select Case UCase(BeforeORAfter)
    Case Is = "BEFORE"
        newColDest = 0  'Inserts column and moves reference column right
    Case Else
        newColDest = 1  'Inserts column to the right of reference column
End Select

'Ensures the user selects a reference column name
Select Case columnName
    Case Is = ""
        columnName = InputBox("Enter column name to be referenced.", "Enter Column Name")
    Case Else
End Select

'Sets the ListObject as the table.
Set loTableName = Range("TableName").ListObject

With loTableName
    On Error GoTo InsertError   'Exits sub in case the column couldn't be found
    .ListColumns.Add (.ListColumns(columnName).Index + newColDest)
End With
Exit Sub

InsertError:
    'Most likely error is user typed the column header incorrectly.
    MsgBox "Error creating column. Ensure a correct reference column was chosen", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Insert Error"

End Sub
```

Any questions or problems, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This below would be something you can work with (it will ask the column to search and perform the actions in your recorded macro...
Check my website http://multiskillz.tekcities.com/k2500_0vbaMenu.html

```
Sub test_modified()

    'worksheet workbook object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    'range object to select a column
    Dim fRng As Variant
    fRng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="value to find", Title:="InputBox Method", Type:=2)

    'range object to find the column
    Dim colRng As Range
    Set colRng = ws.Rows(1)

    'find column
    Dim fcol As Range
    Set fcol = colRng.Find(fRng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

    'convert the column address to a number
    Dim colNb As Byte
    colNb = fcol.Column

    'going on from your recorded macro
    'Columns("L:L").Select
    ws.Columns(colNb).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-6]=R[-1]C[-6],R[-1]C+1,1)"
    Range("L2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Calculate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Cheers
Pascal